# How to export data in bulk from SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, export-to-csv

We run a SaaS software in asp.net for billing. Some of our larger clients want to export billing data in excel in 1 click, for a period of as much as 5 years. In this case there are almost half a million rows. If I export data by using SQLReader and reading from SQL Azure, the Database DTU and the application server CPU both go through the roof. So I replaced the app server with Azure functions. Now I need a workaround for the high Database DTU when 500,000 rows are being read. **Is there a quick and simpler way to export huge sets of data from SQL Azure into a CSV**

Thank you.

Comment: we use bcp for sql server dumps.  you might can try that with azure.. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/bcp-and-sql-azure/

Comment: Maybe [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-sql-connector) could be a good fit. You can then export the data to a [CSV file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-supported-file-and-compression-formats#text-format) which you can read in excel.

Comment: @JamieD77 have you used bcp on azure app service? Since I cannot install anything in the app service environment, I was wondering if bcp is available by default?

Comment: we had to install sql client tools to get bcp to work on a server without sql server installed.  but i believe you can include the files in your build/bin folder and get it to work